# Checking .NET Framework with WIX

Tags: c#-4.0, wix

I am creating an custom installer which have some complected operation to run. I am using custom action by making DLL. But this DLL cannot work if the computer have not .Net Framework installed. My requirement is to install .Net Framework when any of the custom action is clicked. Can not find any clue. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use a bootstrapper/chainer to install .NET Framework before launching your MSI. This can be accomplished with the WiX toolset by creating a `Bundle`. Bundles are available in WiX v3.6 and later, you'll see them as a new project type in Visual Studio.

The WiX Manual provides this: [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Burn](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm)

Comment: `bootstrapper/chainer` will enforce calling .Net installer. I do not want to call `dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe` if it is already installed in that computer.

Comment: If you follow the instructions provided above, it will only download and install NETFX if it is not installed on the machine. The `Burn` bootstrapper/chainer in the WiX toolset is quite smart.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your help it works fine. Now I want to include offline installer of .NET framework. Your link works for install from web. Or I want to keep a button to run .NET installer in my custom dialog. how to do that?

Comment: @pcbabu, sounds like a new more complicated question. Consider opening a new one since comments in StackOverflow are limited.